# Adding WFFM-form - Jquery issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers

I'm using Sitecore 8 Update 2 to make a page where people can leave some personal information. If the user is logged in the information is filled in for them.
( Standard mvc 5 form )

I added a WFFM ( 8.0 rev 141217 ) login form ( if succesfull the page is reloaded and all the fields get filled in) but when this code is included it messes up Jquery.

```
        @Html.Sitecore().Placeholder("form")
```

[image]

I can still see that the jquery file is loaded in the browser but the "Jquery" variable is now undefined. ( and i have a bunch of Jquery running on that page )

[image]

What can i do to prevent this from happening or how can i find out what causes this ?

EDIT:

I found the code where it all goes bad.
After this function is finished the Jquery variable is undefined. But this code is added as part of the WFFM as far as i can tell. ( inline with the html elements )

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (typeof ($scw) === "undefined") {
        window.$scw = jQuery.noConflict(true);
    }
    $scw(document).ready(function () {            
        $scw("#LVn73Spq0EGYvPQZ7-bA5Q").eventTracking({ pageId: "{55D3F49D-6EDA-43FB-81F1-191D34F896D4}", rules: "{&quot;*&quot;:&quot;{844BBD40-91F6-42CE-8823-5EA4D089ECA2}&quot;,&quot;regex&quot;:&quot;{F3D7B20C-675C-4707-84CC-5E5B4481B0EE}&quot;,&quot;length&quot;:&quot;{F3D7B20C-675C-4707-84CC-5E5B4481B0EE}&quot;,&quot;required&quot;:&quot;{7E86B2F5-ACEC-4C60-8922-4EB5AE5D9874}&quot;}" });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What is the order of registered javascript files? Are you sure that your js file is linked **after** `jquery.min.js`?

Comment: <script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>

Is the very first script tag.

I've placed debug points in my custom script and the jquery script and it first gets to jquery.min.js

Comment: That is know issue by Sitecore, I had a chance to talk to them about WFFM 8.0 2 weeks ago they asked me if had met the issue of overriding $ variable by WFFM

Comment: Did you register the wffm script bundles in your code somewhere? You need to add `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/wffm/jquery")` and `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/wffm/scripts")` at least into `/Views/Form/Index.cshtml`

Answer (score 4):

You need to include the WFFM script bundles in your forms. You can do this by registering the scripts in `/Views/Form/Index.cshtml`

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/wffm/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/wffm/scripts")
@Styles.Render("~/content/wffm/jquery")
@Styles.Render("~/content/wffm/themes")
```

You only need to include the first two, the others adds default styling using jQuery UI themes, which you can then override (or not include them and style them yourself).

The reason for the js error is `jQuery.noConflict(true)` resets the jQuery name from scope. The WFFM noConflict call removes the last loaded jQuery library, which in this case is your manually loaded script earlier in the page and since it is the only jQuery library it has nothing to fall back to.

> If necessary, you can free up the jQuery name as well by passing true
>   as an argument to the method. This is rarely necessary, and if you
>   must do this (for example, if you need to use multiple versions of the
>   jQuery library on the same page)

See [jQuery.noConflict()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) and [this blog post](http://sundropsoftware.com/how-to-use-jquery-noconflict-the-right-way/) for more details about loading two versions of jQuery

If you are sure the version if jQuery you loaded is compatible with the WFFM loaded version then you could simply set `window.$scw = jQuery;` but you will still need to load the scripts bundle since it includes form specific functionality.

Comment: I did this, but it doesn't seem to work. Do i need to do anything else ? This is what was added by the render method: <link href="/wffm-bundles/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="/wffm-bundles/scripts.js"></script>

Comment: What's the order of your js inclusion? i.e. Which DOM element is your jQuery and additional js added?

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same error occurring on a site. The error occurred due to the fact that I had included all the wffm jquery references at the bottom of the `<body>` element. After moving the wffm jquery references into the `<head>` element and reloaded the page I had no errors in my console.

Comment: This worked for me. WFFM uses @Html.RenderScripts, so WFFM scripts will be added to the `<head>`. Moving your own scripts into the `<head>` makes sure they are loaded before the WFFM scripts.

Answer (score 0):

**Regarding the order of loading JavaScript files while bundling**:

Preferably your project makes use of properly closured js files, (scoped usage of `jQuery` or `$`). If that's the case, you can simply load the WFFM scripts as the last library, even after your own custom application code.
That way these scripts will ommit the global jQuery variable while your closures keep reference to jQuery locally. Hence this is a great example why using an [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) is encouraged.

```
(function($){
    // $ = reference to jQuery remains intact
}(window.jQuery))
```

I can now savely load my bundle from the head with the async property enabled (eliminates [render-blocking JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/BlockingJS#deferJS) to increase page loading speed).

```
<head>
    ...
    @Scripts.RenderFormat("<script src='{0}' async='async'></script>", Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsPageEditor
    ? "/scripts/sdw.editor.bundle.js"
    : "/scripts/sdw.web.bundle.js");
    ...
</head>
```

A bundle example in order <sup>(In **bold** the `WFFM` requirements for the `Experience Editor`)</sup>:

1. **jQuery** *(bower updated version inside Experience Editor works usually fine)*
2. **jQuery-UI** *(WFFM dependency)*
3. Bootstrap
4. **jQuery validation** *(WFFM dependency)*
5. **jQuery unobtrusive validation** *(WFFM dependency)*
6. My custom JS *(still applicable for the editor?)*
7. **WFFM Scripts** *(sitecore modules > Web > Web Forms for Marketers > scripts > mvc > Fields > *.js)*

---

On the other hand, `jQuery` dependant code from inline scripts or external js files, loaded before the closing `</body>`, don't know about `jQuery` anymore once the WFFM scripts are loaded. Either split them up or define `$scw` before loading WFFM scripts.

An example of bundling while mixing inline scripts:

```
<head>
    ...
    @Scripts.Render("~bundles/libraries") // jQuery, jQuery-UI, Bootstrap, jQuery validation, ...
    <script>window.$scw = jQuery.noConflict(false);</script>
    @Scripts.Render("~bundles/wffmJs")
</head>
<body>
    ...
    <script type="text/javascript">
        if (typeof ($scw) === "undefined") {
            window.$scw = jQuery.noConflict(true);
        }
        $scw(document).ready(function () {
            $scw("#@Model.ID.ToShortGuid()").eventTracking({ pageId: "@Model.PageId", rules: "@TrackingValidationErrorsProvider.Current.GetValidationRulesMap()" });
        });
    </script>
    ...
    @Scripts.Render("~bundles/myCustomJs")
</body>
```

---

**Conclusion:**

- Avoid synchronous loading from the head tag since that will block rendering and result in slower page loading.
- Avoid inline `script` tags because they force you to load libraries from the head tag synchronously.
- Define `$scw = jQuery` to bypass `jQuery.noConflict(true)` if needed.
- Preferably one bundle asynchronously from the head tag.
- Use closure to keep libraries referenced.